# When I use stat_smooth the trendline does not show in the figure

Tags: r

I have a data have 6 column named: DBF, BF, MM, TC, TA, and DL. I used them as variable. And use a column named hardwood.content as my independent variable. I used the following code in r.

```
printf("%d\n", 42)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
nrn <- melt(nrn, inrn.vars="hardwood.content") 
ggplot(nrn, aes(hardwood.content,value)) + 
geom_point() + 
stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE,colour='black')+
facet_wrap(~variable)+
xlab("Hardwood content (%)")+ylab("Number of regeneration per ha")
```

It should have a trendline in the figure but in my figure there is no trendline show up. I am not sure what is wrong with this problem.

This is the figure I got.

[image]

the data is

```
hardwood    DBF      BF         MM       TC      TA     DL
0-25        15250    41206.8    5000     0       5000   0
0-25        8846.1   40517.2    0        0       0      0
0-25        10833.3  30967.7    20833.3  0       0      0
40-65       8750     14250      7884.6   42500   0      7727.2
40-65       0        20217.3    13043.4  0       0      8571.4
40-65       7500     12948.7    15000    25833.3 5000   8750
75-95       0        10000      13225.8  7500    5000   0
75-95       0        5000       10517.2  53461.5 5000   33095.2
75-95       5000     8666.6     7600     20000   5000   18965.5
```

Comment: It must be something to do with your dataset. If you replace your dataset with the built-in `iris` dataset (ie. replace nrn with iris, etc.), your code for the plot works fine. How about editing your question to include your data (or some of it)?

Comment: @Ben, I am not sure how to load my data. I try copy them but it looks messy. Do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: Just use the command `dput(your dataset)`

Comment: For `lm` to work correctly, `hardwood.content` should be numerical. Is that the case ?

Comment: @ Erwan LE PENNEC, when I use as.numeric (hardwood.content). The value "0-25, 40-65, 75-100" become "1, 2, 3". How I can fix that?